# Finding mean of groups with loop in R

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, matrix

I would like to find the mean of the groups which are classified as answer_options. Unfortunately i could not even build the structure to solve the problem.

```
 answer_options <- c(3,3,3,2,2,4,4,4,4)
 options <- c(33,32,31,10,15,5,5,6,6)
 dd <- data.matrix(cbind(answer_options,options))
```

In order to count then finding the mean of the groups, i need to find first group has 3 values which are 32,32,31. Then calculate the first mean via 1.group then begin answer_options[1+3] -which is 2- then repeat this again.

For instance:

1.group: c(3,3,3) and its mean equals mean(33,32,31)
2.group: c(2,2) and its mean equals mean(10,15)
3.group: c(4,4,4,4) and its mean equals mean(5,5,6,6)

Then I need to calculate the mean of the means.

```
 c3 <- answer_options
##for i do not know how? 
 a1 <- c3[1]+1 
 a2 <- c3[a1]
 a3 <- c3[a1+c3[a1]]
 a4 <- c3[c3[a1+c3[a1]]]
 a5 <- c3[c3[1]+1 +c3[a1]+c3[a1+c3[a1]]]
```

the sequence should be like that:

1. 1
2. c3[1.]
3. c3[1.+2.]
4. c3[1.+2.+3.]
   .
   .
   .

I am disturbed by this problem, i hope that you will help me! Thanks a lot.

edit: In order to ask my question clear, i edit some additional info.

Comment: Not clear what you need to do

Comment: Try `ave(options, answer_options, FUN=mean)` which calculates the mean of `options`, grouped by `answer_options`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for ave(options, answer_options, FUN=mean) options. However, as a next step i need to calculate the mean of the means.  and this option provides this. I do not how can i calculate the means eventhough unique function seems like work, but i have a big data to work. 
[1] 32.0 32.0 32.0 12.5 12.5  5.5  5.5  5.5  5.5

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if a data frame will work for you instead of a matrix. I use dplyr to do what you are asking. I'm not a expert programmer, so this may be inefficient.

```
answer_options <- c(3,3,3,2,2,4,4,4,4)
options <- c(33,32,31,10,15,5,5,6,6)
dd <- data.frame(cbind(answer_options,options))
```

Using the %>% piping function in dplyr gives you the summary information in a dataframe:

```
   library(dplyr)
   new.dd <- dd %>% group_by(answer_options) %>% 
    summarise(n=n(),
              mean_answer_options=mean(options))


     answer_options     n mean_answer_options
           (dbl) (int)               (dbl)
1              2     2                12.5
2              3     3                32.0
3              4     4                 5.5
```

Then merge the two tables.

```
merged.dd<-left_join(dd,new.dd,by="answer_options")
merged.dd
  answer_options options n mean_answer_options
1              3      33 3                32.0
2              3      32 3                32.0
3              3      31 3                32.0
4              2      10 2                12.5
5              2      15 2                12.5
6              4       5 4                 5.5
7              4       5 4                 5.5
8              4       6 4                 5.5
9              4       6 4                 5.5
```

**EDITED TO ADDRESS OP COMMENT BELOW HERE**

You would need to have another variable that uniquely identifies each case you want to summarize.   Such as "question".

```
question<-c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4)
answer_options <- c(3,3,3,2,2,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4)
options <- c(33,32,31,10,15,5,5,6,6,1,1,2,2)

dd <- data.frame(cbind(question,answer_options,options)) 
dd

library(dplyr)
new.dd <- dd %>% group_by(question) %>% 
    summarise(n=n(),mean_options_question=mean(options))
new.dd

merged.dd<-left_join(dd,new.dd,by="question")
merged.dd
```

This will give you the following output.

```
   question answer_options options n mean_options_question
1         1              3      33 3                  32.0
2         1              3      32 3                  32.0
3         1              3      31 3                  32.0
4         2              2      10 2                  12.5
5         2              2      15 2                  12.5
6         3              4       5 4                   5.5
7         3              4       5 4                   5.5
8         3              4       6 4                   5.5
9         3              4       6 4                   5.5
10        4              4       1 4                   1.5
11        4              4       1 4                   1.5
12        4              4       2 4                   1.5
13        4              4       2 4                   1.5
```

Comment: In re-reading your post, I am not sure this is what you were asking for. I don't quite understand your requested output.

Comment: mainly it is correct. but it is not working well as i want in one condition. If i have a new group(4th group) which has 4 answer options again, the code will take the mean of 3.and 4. together. please try with these
    

answer_options <- c(3,3,3,2,2,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4)
options <- c(33,32,31,10,15,5,5,6,6,1,1,2,2)
dd <- data.frame(cbind(answer_options,options))

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question, you want to calculate the means of the means of the group, am I correct? If so, the following code will first calculate out the means of each group (Note that I am turning your input into a dataframe and not a matrix):

```
# Your input as a dataframe and not a matrix
> answer_options <- c(3,3,3,2,2,4,4,4,4)
> options <- c(33,32,31,10,15,5,5,6,6)
> dd <- data.frame(cbind(answer_options,options))

# Calculates the mean of each group and puts it into a "mean_ 
# _answer_options" vector
> mean_answer_options = by(dd$options,answer_options, FUN = mean)
> mean_answer_options
answer_options: 2
[1] 12.5
 -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
answer_options: 3
[1] 32
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
answer_options: 4
[1] 5.5
```

you can calculate the mean of the means of each group by using the following command:

```
> mean(as.numeric(mean_answer_options))
[1] 16.66667
```

This generates the correct mean of 16.66667 for the means of each group. This can be cross checked by:

```
> (12.5+32+5.5)/3
[1] 16.66667
```

If this is not what you are asking for, can you clarify anything that I might have misunderstood? Hope this helps!